# WebDAV Server Error 401.2, connection issue with Windows Authentication after pausing virtual server/domain controller

Tags: iis, webdav

We are connecting to a webdav server through IIS 6 using iPads running iAnnotate. Friday we performed some maintenance where all we really did was pause the virtual server/domain controller where the webdav is setup.

Ever since we did that, we are able to browse the webdav connection from iAnnotate on the iPads but when we try to sync a file back (PUT method I'm assuming) we get an error 411, which actually appears to be error "HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized. You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers", according to IIS.

Does anyone have any thoughts or ideas on this?

Answer (score 1):

We figured out what was causing our issue although I may not be able to explain entirely why it mattered.

In IIS there is a setting in the "HTTP Response Headers" under "Set Common Headers" called "Enable HTTP keep-alive". We check marked this option as true and our Windows Authentication started working again.

It seemed to have something to do with the connection not staying open between requests and the application or IIS not realizing the connection was restarted during the SYNC operation.